# MDX calculated member filtration uses measure

Tags: mdx, ssas-2012

I need help with calculated member
I have this code

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Summary distribution by CSKU]
 AS count(
    NONEMPTY(
        crossjoin(
                descendants ([05_Goods].[CSKU].currentmember,,LEAVES),
                descendants ([04_Agents].[Agents hierarhy],,LEAVES)
            )        
        )
), 
FORMAT_STRING = "###,##0;-###,##0", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Quantity] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Distribution' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = '01_Sales'  ;
```

but I want to see a result without elements where sum([Measures].[Sales amount]) <> 0

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see other choice than using the [MDX Filter function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.html) :

```
 ...
 AS count(
   FILTER(  
    crossjoin(
            descendants ([05_Goods].[CSKU].currentmember,,LEAVES),
            descendants ([04_Agents].[Agents hierarhy],,LEAVES)
        )
    ,  [Measures].[Sales amount] <> 0)
    )
```

You might try adding the NonEmpty to the descendants method to improve performance  (if some descendants have no [Sales Amount].